# Why does MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter create a JSON array and not a JSON string?

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services

I am using MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and I want it to create a JSON String - the body for a PUT request. The problem that I am having is that it only seems to create a JSON array (it is adding square brackets).

Please can somebody see what I need to do differently?

```
        VerifiedOrder verifiedOrder = new VerifiedOrder();
        verifiedOrder.setVerified_order_number(verifiedOrderNumber);
        logger.warn("verifiedOrder=" + verifiedOrder.toString());

        String ambiguousOrderVerificationResponseMessage = AppHubStringUtil.EMPTY_STRING;
        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();

        try {
            requestBody.put("verified_order_id", verifiedOrderNumber);
            logger.warn("requestBody=" + requestBody.toString());

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody.toString(), headers);
            logger.warn("entity=" + entity.toString());

            ResponseEntity<String> ambiguousOrderVerificationResponse = restTemplate.exchange(webserviceUrl.toString(), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
            ambiguousOrderVerificationResponseMessage = ambiguousOrderVerificationResponse.getStatusCode().toString();
            logger.warn("ambiguousOrderVerificationResponse.getStatusCode()=" + ambiguousOrderVerificationResponseMessage);}
```

I have deliberately omitted the catch...but that is where I always end up. The output in the logging is as follows:

> 2017-01-09 14:03:58,650 AmbiguousOrderVerificationServiceImpl [WARN] requestBody={"verified_order_id":"22222222"}
>   2017-01-09 14:03:58,650 AmbiguousOrderVerificationServiceImpl [WARN] entity=<{"verified_order_id":"22222222"},{Content-Type=[application/json]}>
>   2017-01-09 14:03:58,653 RestTemplate [DEBUG] Created PUT request for "http://devtlnx0157.stbc2.jstest2.net:15100/v03/ambiguous-customer-orders-utility-noauth/202"
>   2017-01-09 14:03:58,653 RestTemplate [DEBUG] Setting request Accept header to [application/json]
>   2017-01-09 14:03:58,658 RestTemplate [DEBUG] Writing [{"verified_order_id":"22222222"}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@1ea6c69]

Notice that the RestTemplate logging message is adding square brackets []

```
2017-01-09 14:03:58,658 RestTemplate [DEBUG] Writing [{"verified_order_id":"22222222"}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@1ea6c69]
```

How do I create a valid JSON message, without the square brackets?

Thank you.

Comment: RestTemplate.this.logger.debug("Writing [" + requestBody + "] as \"" search this line in Resttemplate

Comment: your request body is valid. Don`t confuse it with the log statement